# Solving euler problem 276

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, triangles, oeis, project-euler

i am trying to solve [Euler problem 276](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=276)

But... i am completely stuck.
I need to find integer triplets $a$, $b$, $c$ such that
$a \leq b \leq c$ and $a+b > c$ and
$\gcd\bigl(a, (\gcd(b, c)\bigr) = 1$.
also, $a+b+c$ must be ${}\leq 10$ million

brute force is not an option, it would take years to check all possible triplets.
i can reduce the numbers a bit (a can only be ${}\leq \tfrac13$ of the perimeter, $b$ can not be ${}> \tfrac12$ perimeter, but this is far from enough.

i checked alcuin's sequence which tells me how many triangles can exist, but it includes those for which $\gcd(a, b, c)$ is different from one

i can already tell by checking for $a + b + c \leq 5000$ that the final number will be huge, so even generating valid triplets with near zero time/effort won't work. i need a way to know some partial sums.

however, i don't know how the things i'm looking for a called. i could use:

- $a$ function which generates values for $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$
- a variant of alcuin's sequence for which $\gcd(a, b, c) = 1$

alternatively, i could use a function for this:
https://oeis.org/A051493
as formula it only says "moebius transform of another sequence". what does this mean? how do i "read oeis pages"?

the main problem is runtime. usually i can break down the problem into smaller parts and reuse partial results, but i see no way how i can apply this strategy here. there is no recursion (that i can see) nor can i see any calculations that repeat.

Comment: I would suggest Euclid's formula for pythagorean triples.  It generates all and  only the primitives.  One thing that is usually left out of explanations is that you need $0 \le m/n \le (\sqrt 2)/(\sqrt 2 + 1)$ to avoid duplicates.  If you work out the full logic of it, you could count the number of triples less than a million digit number (a true polytime algorithm).

Comment: the problem isn't about right angled triangles. about m & n: aren't thoses uosed to be integers? if it's < sqrt(2) i only get 0 or 1

Comment: You have to look up Euclid's formula for generating pythagorean triples for that to make sense.

Comment: again: the problem is not restricted to right angled triangles. i do not see how to apply euclid's formula here.

Comment: i also don't understand what you mean by sqrt(2) after reading this: https://www.adrian.idv.hk/2012-08-09-euclid/

Comment: Oops I miswrote that part, it should have been $\sqrt 2 / (\sqrt 2 + 2)$

Comment: Why 10 million, but not 10 billion?

Comment: the upper limit is arbitary

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint (giving a solution would be cheating):

1. The triplets with gcd of 1 are all triplets regardless of gcd, except those with a gcd of 2, or a gcd of 3, or a gcd of 4, ... or a gcd of n.
2. You get all triplets with a gcd of k and a sum ≤ n by taking all triplets with a gcd of 1 and a sum ≤ floor(n/k). and multiplying a, b, c by k.

Let f(n) be the number of triplets with a sum ≤ n. (1) or (2) give you a simple recursion formula for f(n). All you need to do is:

a. Whenever f(k) has been calculated, remember the result and don't calculate it again.

b. Observe that in your recursion formula you often calculate f(k) for small k very often. For example while calculating f(10,000,000), the recursion formula will tell you to subtract f(1) exactly 5,000,000 times.

Comment: "You count all triplets" > simply looping through the triplets without any further logic will take weeks (or months, or years). the rest of your proposal i do not understand.

Comment: @user1471827 I assume you can find a formula for the number of triplets without the gcd condition.

Comment: yes, i already have it

Comment: i seem to be missing something- how can you define this thing as a recursion? once t hat's possible, yes, i can use caching. and why do i want triplets with a gcd != 1? i don't see how any of your hints should help. how do i get the  numbers without O(n³)?

Comment: maybe i should make clear where i am stuck? perimeter,a and b are my values i need to loop over. then i filter gbc(a,b,c)=1. it is a nested loop. i do not see how this can be turned into a recursion. i also see no pattern, no repetition to exploit. i can't create a lookup-table for (b,c) for example to store artial sums since the gcd also depends on a. the sum always depends on 3 parameters, or am i wrong?

Comment: everything you wrote is totally obvious to me (and already was before), i just don't see how i could apply it or how it helps. yes, gcd != 1 is gcd > 1. but if i could count the cases gcd != 1, i would have solved the problem already. yes, 1*k=k, but how does this help with anything? it's only useful if i already have the cases gcd = 1, and then i already solved the problem. i don't have the function "f" you assume i could find. i don't see how one follows from 1. or 2.